# How to compare ip addresses in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to perform compare two ip address.

This is the model:

```
public partial class CityIp
{
    [Key]
    public string IpStart { get; set; }
    public string IpEnd { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

My DB holds 6M rows of the model above.
I get an ip address and I have to understand: is it between ipStart and ipEnd?
I store ipStart and ipEnd as nvarchar, but I'm not sure that it correct way.

What is the best way to compare it?

I think it's not good to pull all rows from db and compare it in C# code. I prefer do it using SQL, but I don't know how to do it.

I need perform something like

```
SELECT 
    Country, Province, City 
FROM 
    CityIP 
WHERE 
    ipStart <= 'myIp' AND 'myIp' <= ipEnd
```

Comment: How are you storing IP addresses? You should be storing them as `int` (for IPv4) or `varbinary(16)` for IPv4+IPv6, not as strings.

Comment: Also, you should ensure that those IP address ranges are internally contiguous.

Comment: If you are storing them as string (!) this might help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) We should store ip addresses using VARBINARY(16)!

```
[Ip] VARBINARY (16) NOT NULL
```

2) To compare if an ip address is in range you can just write

```
SELECT * FROM CityIp WHERE IpStart <= @IpAddress AND @IpAddress <= IpEnd
```

Where IpStart, IpAddress, IpEnd are VARBINARY(16).

3) To work with ip address we should use `System.Net.IPAddress`. You can call `GetAddressBytes()` to get bytes of your ip

So, my model looks like this

```
public partial class CityIp
{
    [Key]
    public byte[] IpStart { get; set; }
    public byte[] IpEnd { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This do the trick:

```
DECLARE @ipaddress nvarchar(16) = N'87.217.221.22'

SELECT *
FROM CityIp
WHERE
    (
        CAST(PARSENAME(IpStart, 4) AS bigint) * 256 * 256 * 256 +
        CAST(PARSENAME(IpStart, 3) AS bigint) * 256 * 256 +
        CAST(PARSENAME(IpStart, 2) AS bigint) * 256 +
        CAST(PARSENAME(IpStart, 1) AS bigint)
    ) 
    <=
    (
        CAST(PARSENAME(@ipaddress, 4) AS bigint) * 256 * 256 * 256  +
        CAST(PARSENAME(@ipaddress, 3) AS bigint) * 256 * 256 +
        CAST(PARSENAME(@ipaddress, 2) AS bigint) * 256 + 
        CAST(PARSENAME(@ipaddress, 1) AS bigint)
    ) 
    AND
    (
        CAST(PARSENAME(IpEnd, 4) AS bigint) * 256 * 256 * 256 +
        CAST(PARSENAME(IpEnd, 3) AS bigint) * 256 * 256 +
        CAST(PARSENAME(IpEnd, 2) AS bigint) * 256 +
        CAST(PARSENAME(IpEnd, 1) AS bigint)
    ) 
    >=
    (
        CAST(PARSENAME(@ipaddress, 4) AS bigint) * 256 * 256 * 256  +
        CAST(PARSENAME(@ipaddress, 3) AS bigint) * 256 * 256 +
        CAST(PARSENAME(@ipaddress, 2) AS bigint) * 256 + 
        CAST(PARSENAME(@ipaddress, 1) AS bigint)
    )
```

Unfortunately the query is slow because a full scan is required.

EDIT
The above query will work with ipv4 addresses. To deal with ipv6 addresses I would use a CLR scalar function like the following:

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction(DataAccess=DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic=true, IsPrecise=true, SystemDataAccess=SystemDataAccessKind.None)]
    [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize=16)]
    public static  SqlBinary TryParseIPAddress([SqlFacet(MaxSize=40)] SqlString iPAddress)
    {
        if (iPAddress.IsNull) return SqlBinary.Null;
        IPAddress address;
        if (IPAddress.TryParse(iPAddress.Value, out address))
        {
            return new SqlBinary(address.GetAddressBytes());
        }
        else return SqlBinary.Null;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
DECLARE @ipaddress varbinary(16) = dbo.TryParseIPAddress( N'2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334')

SELECT *
FROM CityIp
WHERE
    dbo.TryParseIPAddress(IpStart) <= @ipaddress
    AND dbo.TryParseIPAddress(IpEnd) >= @ipaddress
```

EDIT:
One thing that would speed up things is adding two binary computed columns that store IpStart and IpEnd in binary format. But the biggest performance improvement would be applying [Relational Interval Tree](http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/VLDB2000.pdf) as shown in the following article:

[Interval Queries in SQL Server](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/sql-server-interval-queries)

Comment: Are they ipv6 addresses?

Comment: Yes, they are ipv6 addresses

Comment: @Kostya Vyrodov ipv6 addresses are imposible to parse with simple T-SQL expressions, scalar functions are required, but they are very slow. Are you willing to use a CLR scalar function?

Comment: I don't know... I think we should try. Can I compare VARBINARY(16) using sql query?

Comment: Please, see my edit. Yes you can compare varbinary(16) columns and variables