# How to check given IP is in between IP ranges(Start IP & End IP)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ip, ip-address

I have one IP address, And I wanted to verify by passing this IP address to SQL Server table, where the SQL Sever table has two columns with start and end range of IP addresses. If I pass the IP address to the query it should check the given ip address is in the table and return the complete row.

Comment: show your table schema  ,  a proper data sample,  the expected . result ...and the code that you tried to write

Comment: also tag the version you are using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server  convert it to binary then do the compare.  or see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177404/select-record-between-two-ip-ranges

Comment: Thanks for replied. It looks I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717815/how-to-compare-ip-addresses-in-sql-server